# Regex for matching all word unless at start of sentance

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all words that begin with an upper case, unless they are at a start of a sentence.

so

> It was in late July that that he found out. He had seen Tim

would return:

July, Tim

so far I've got

```
(?!<*[\\s])([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)
```

but get "He" and "It" included.

Comment: It is probably`(?<![.?!]\s|^)[A-Z][A-Za-z]+`

Comment: Do you plan to encounter poetry? https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/148387/uptown-minneapolis-minnesota

Comment: What about those people who are ingrained to add two spaces after a period? `It was in late July that that he found out.  He had seen Tim`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus they can burn in hell! ...but also nice catch. I'm using Java

Comment: How do you define "start of a sentence"?

Comment: @WhatTheWhat I legitimately 

Comment: @AndyLester i suppose when a word with a capital letter is preceded by a double space or a period and then a space or nothing

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP didn't explicitly state this but your solution would miss the `I` in `It was in late July that that I found out. He had seen Tim`

Comment: What about acronyms? `U.S.A.`

Comment: You gotta love the rabbit hole known as language constructs when dealing with a tool designed for characters with no contextual-awareness =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is not my restriction, it is OP's pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm aware. I'm just pointing out that there is a myriad of things OP hasn't considered.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew many thanks for your answer, this gives me a sound footing to start thinking about the problem a bit more. Please add this as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus your comments have indeed made me realize how woefully ignorant I was of the question. I shall go away and think about this some more. Thanks guys

Comment: @WhatTheWhat I'm not suggesting that you go away. You have been more responsive than 99% of the people I interact with in situations like this. You're respectably responsive and willing to re-think your needs instead of treating it as a homework punchlist and getting angry when requested to critically think.

Comment: Also, consider this fun one `Luke saw C-3PO enter the ship`

Comment: @Alderath You're possibly not wrong there. My task is to redact proper nouns from a book, without importing a dictionary and ignoring words at the beginning of sentences. Happy to take other suggestions

Comment: And who could ignore `Elon Musk wants to name his child X Æ A-12.` or `As a great man once said "Live long and Star War!" - Sir George Washington.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using a lookaround like

```
(?<![.?!]\s|^)[A-Z][A-Za-z]+
```

Note this will match words of two or more ASCII letters. If one-letter words are to be found, too, replace `+` at the end with a `*` quantifier.

If you plan to check for whole words only, add word boundaries, `\b(?<![.?!]\s|^)[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\b`

The `(?<![.?!]\s|^)` is a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately prececed with a `.` / `?` / `!` and a whitespace, or start of string location.

Comment: Thank you very much, how could i add to this ignore anything that doesn't have any char before it. For example:
`All her invitations without exception, were written in French. But it was all rubbish.`
using `(?<![.?!]\s)[A-Z][a-z]+` returns "All" and "French" where i really just want "French"

Comment: @WhatTheWhat See https://regex101.com/r/GmL1pF/1. You are not using my regex.

Comment: Quite right, apologies!